# Когда потоки в Python выполняются последовательно, а когда вразнобой?

Tags: python, многопоточность

Разбираюсь с потоками, дошёл до пула потоков ThreadPoolExecutor и тут возник вопрос. При запуске кода:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed

def f(a):
    return a * a

# .shutdown() in exit
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as pool:
    results = [pool.submit(f, i) for i in range(10)]

    for future in as_completed(results):
        print(future.result())
```

Печатается упорядоченная последовательность вывода работы каждого future:

```
0
1
4
9
16
25
36
49
64
81
```

Однако, если запустить код иначе (вне контекстного менеджера):

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed

def f(a):
    return a * a

# .shutdown() in exit
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as pool:
    results = [pool.submit(f, i) for i in range(10)]

for future in as_completed(results):
    print(future.result())
```

То сразу возникает анархия в виде неупорядоченного вывода. Например,

```
64
0
4
9
36
16
81
49
1
25
```

Подскажите, в чём разница между этими примерами? Когда потоки выполняются последовательно, а когда вразнобой? От чего это зависит?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В обоих случаях, расчет функции f происходит параллельно.

На время работы потока никогда нельзя полагаться. Поэтому нельзя полагаться на порядок объектов возвращаемых as_completed. Вам повезло, что время выполнения функции f было каждый раз примерно одинаковым, и потоки завершались в том же порядке, в каком были поставлены в очередь pool-а. Если нужно обработать результаты в заданной последовательности, просто ждите каждого результата по отдельности:

```
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as pool:
    results = [pool.submit(f, i) for i in range(10)]
    for future in results:
        print(future.result())
```

Чем отличаются два ваших примера? Тем что выход из контекста `with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as pool:` означает закрытие пула потоков, т.е. выход произойдет только после тока как все поставленные в очередь задачи будут выполнены. Т.е. во втором примере вызов `as_completed` бессмысленен. В случае если к моменту вызова as_completed часть future уже выполнена, то as_completed возвращает их первыми, но не гарантирует относительный порядок. Что мы и видим во 2-м примере.

Answer (score 1):

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed
from collections import OrderedDict

func = lambda a: a * a
args = list(range(10))

# 1) результаты придут одномоментно, в том же порядке что и в args
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as pool:
    results = pool.map(func, args)  # одномоментно
    print(OrderedDict(zip(args, results)))

# 2) результаты придут последовательно, в том же порядке что и в args,
#    но если первая future будет выполнятся дольше всего,
#    то в results ничего не попадет, пока её выполнение не закончится.
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as pool:
    results = []
    for future in [pool.submit(func, i) for i in args]:
        try:
            result = future.result()  # последовательно
        except Exception as ex:
            results.append(None)  # можно обработать возможные ошибки при выполнении
        else:
            results.append(result)
        continue
    print(OrderedDict(zip(args, results)))

# 3) результаты придут последовательно, в порядке времени выполнения
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as pool:
    futures = {pool.submit(func, i): i for i in args}  # соответствие future/args
    results = OrderedDict()
    for future in as_completed(futures):  # в порядке времени выполнения
        arg = futures[future]
        results[arg] = future.result()
        continue
    print(results)

# OrderedDict([(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 4), (3, 9), (4, 16), (5, 25), (6, 36), (7, 49), (8, 64), (9, 81)])
# OrderedDict([(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, 4), (3, 9), (4, 16), (5, 25), (6, 36), (7, 49), (8, 64), (9, 81)])
# OrderedDict([(1, 1), (0, 0), (2, 4), (3, 9), (4, 16), (5, 25), (6, 36), (7, 49), (8, 64), (9, 81)])
```